# как сделать поиск по адресу js

Tags: javascript, поиск

Есть сайт https://fair.cashofferoption.com/get-offer/.
когда начинаем вводить адрес\индекс - нам предлает с гугл карт подсказку адреса. как такое копировать?

видел что там есть скрипт гугл карт, но что с ним делать дальше не понимаю

Comment: Можно начать [отсюда](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete?hl=ru).

Comment: спасибо!!! путь верный